# Code folding in Live Scripts

Tags: matlab, code-formatting

Is there a way to fold sections of codes in [Live Scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-live-scripts.html#bu6g0df-1) as there is in regular scripts?

I have tried to look for it in the preferences and enabled all kind of foldings, but none of them relate to the Live Scripts. I would expect it to work since the notation of `%%` is similar in both types of scripts.

Any idea how to enable/workaround this?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe you can do this. Seems like a nice thing to want to do, though, so I would enter an enhancement request with MathWorks. I have no suggestion for a workaround, I'm afraid.

Comment: How can I suggest an enhancement request to MathWorks?

Comment: Go to mathworks.com, log in with your account. Go to the support section and create a new support request. Select the option "Enhancement Request" or "Feature Request" (can't remember which, I'm afraid). Enter the details, and if possible try to explain the benefits you will see from the new feature - this helps the developers to prioritise it. You'll get a message back from support, probably asking for more details, and it'll be put in a queue for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but in case anyone else is wondering, below are the workarounds suggested to me by tech support when I submitted an enhancement request. I encourage the reader to add their vote by submitting a request if they still want to see this feature added to the live editor.

> 1. Convert to M file and "publish" with 'showcode' as false. First, convert the Live Script into an M file.  You can do this interactively
>    by clicking "Save As" and then choosing the "M" file option in the
>    File Type section or you can do it programmatically as follows:
>
>    >> matlab.internal.liveeditor.openAndConvert('live_script_to_be_converted.mlx',
>    'output_script.m');
>
> Once you have the converted M file which has all the section breaks
> and formatting, you can use the "publish" function as follows from the
> MATLAB Command Window:
>
> >> options.format = 'pdf';
> >> options.showCode = false;
> >> publish('output_script.m',options)
>
> This will publish the PDF file to a sub-directory called "html" inside
> the current working directory.
>
> Here is a documentation link for the "publish" function and
> specifically, the "showCode" option:
> https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html#input_argument_namevalue_d119e823467
>
> Please note, when saving the MLX file as M file and then publishing,
> it does not convert the LaTeX expressions to something readable. It
> also automatically inserts a table of contents at the beginning.
>
> 2. Encapsulate the code in another script or function. An alternate approach would be for you to encapsulate the code you want to hide in
>    another script or function and call it from your published Live
>    Script. For example, something like:
>
>    >> %% Now plot a figure
>    >> functionThatPlotsAFigure
>
> In this case, instead of publishing all the plotting code, only the
> call to the plotting function would be published.
>
> 3. Publish the Live Script as an HTML and then modify the HTML page to hide the code sections and then publish it as a PDF.
>
> The options stated above are simply workarounds as we do not currently have this functionality. A request has been submitted to our developers to add in this feature and they are considering this for future releases of MATLAB. We appreciate your feedback as we constantly strive to improve our products.